# Cast from 'Data?' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails

Tags: swift4, alamofire, xcode9

> Cast from 'Data?' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails

Here, I am trying to fetch the response from Api and using alamofire for the first time but i am getting above warning please help me out

```
guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
    print("Didn't get todo object as JSON from API")
    if let error = response.result.error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    return
}
```

what shall I change if any please help.

Answer (score 0):

The change you have to make is one line above.

You have to tell the request to get the deserialized response rather than the raw `Data`

```
Alamofire.request( [...] ).responseJSON {
```

Comment: as can please describe in more detail i am new to swift and alamofire and one more thing i have used responseData Alamofire.request(todosEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: newTodo,
                          encoding: URLEncoding.default,headers:nil)
            .responseData { response in
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                    print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
                    print(response.result.error!)
                    return
                }

Comment: Just replace `responseData` with `responseJSON`

Comment: did so but while executing the program i am getting the below error :-- responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength) at   'guard response.result.error == nil'

Comment: let todosEndpoint: String = "abcdefg?"
        let newTodo: [String: Any] = ["ss": "M","ddd":"A","hhhh":"cc","vvvv":604808,"nnnb":524]
        Alamofire.request(todosEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: newTodo,
                          encoding: URLEncoding.default,headers:nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
                    print(response.result.error!)
                    return}

Comment: please suggest me how to fix this

Comment: Please ask a new question. The runtime error is not related to this one.

Answer (score 0):

If your `response.result.value` is JSON data, you can obtain it as:

```
guard let jsonData = response.result.value {
    let responseObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
    if let response = responseObj as? [String: Any] { print(response) }
}
```